# In python WindowsError: [Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'F:/Dataset\\*.*'

Tags: python, windows

```
for category in CATEGORIES:  # do dogs and cats
    path = os.path.join(DATADIR,category)  # create path to dogs and cats
    for img in os.listdir(path):  # iterate over each image per dogs and cats
        img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,img) ,cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)  # convert to array
        plt.imshow(img_array, cmap='gray')  # graph it
        plt.show()  # display!
```

error occurred :

```
WindowsErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-be2d68025f07> in <module>()
      1 for category in CATEGORIES:  # do dogs and cats
      2     path = os.path.join(DATADIR,category)  # create path to dogs and cats
----> 3     for img in os.listdir(path):  # iterate over each image per dogs and cats
      4         img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,img) ,cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)  # convert to array
      5         plt.imshow(img_array, cmap='gray')  # graph it

WindowsError: [Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'F:/Dataset\\Bening\\*.*'
```

Comment: The error literally says the path is wrong. Firstly, paths in Python don't use wildcards `*.*`, as you can see it's a `.listdir`, so you pass a directory in there. If you want to use wildcards, try `glob`. Moreover, you use wrong separator in your definition of `DATADIR` - `os.path.join` uses the system-specific one which is backslash in Windows (double backslash in print because it needs escaping), you use a normal, forward slash.

Comment: @h4z3 Please post an answer as an answer, not as a comment

Comment: @FlyingTeller That wasn't a full structured answer, hence it was made into a comment. Fixing typos etc is to be made in the comments. But if you insist...

Answer (score 1):

```
WindowsError: [Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'F:/Dataset\\Bening\\*.*'
```

The error literally says the path is wrong.

Let's look more closely:

We have `os.listdir(path)` with an error caused by `'F:/Dataset\\Bening\\*.*'`

Firstly, paths in Python don't use wildcards *.*. It's an `os.listdir`, so you pass a directory in there. If you want to use wildcards, try `glob`.

Secondly, you use wrong separator in your definition of `DATADIR` - `os.path.join` uses the system-specific one which is backslash in Windows (double backslash in print because it needs escaping), you use a normal, forward slash. You can put the path with backslashes by putting `r` just before opening the string (it means the string is raw - backslashes are literal, not an escaping sequence) or by doubling the backslashes manually. `r'F:\Dataset'` or `'F:\\Dataset`

Comment: Windows will accept / as a path separator just fine, or even a mix of \ and / together. While the printed path looks ugly, it's valid and not part of the issue.

Comment: So the first thing is the issue. <shrugs> That's why I didn't want to make an answer out of my comment, my comment was just that, a quick comment of the issues I see, not a definitive pointer where's the issue.

Comment: Not necessarily, ooa. Some commands / API calls don't like mixed directory separators in a path. While consistently using / or consistently using \ will often work, mixing them often causes an Error 3 - Path not found.